# Pandas: calculating percentage change based on other criteria

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

In the following dataset, I have "cross up" and "cross down".
I'd like to calculate percentage change from cross-down to the next cross-up.

E.g. the first row is "cross up" and the next three rows are "up"
Their prices are
`390.3800`, `389.9000` `389.9500`
The cross down price is then
`388.8600`
I'd like for the three up rows to calculate the change until the cross down. So,
`pct_diff(388.8600, 390.3800)` for the first row
`pct_diff(388.8600, 389.9000)` for the second row
`pct_diff(388.8600, 389.9500)` for the third row

```
2022-07-08 11:30:00  0.780577  0.730154  0.050422        up    cross up  390.3800
2022-07-08 11:45:00  0.798424  0.743808  0.054616        up           0  389.9000
2022-07-08 12:00:00  0.807296  0.756506  0.050790        up           0  389.9500
2022-07-08 12:15:00  0.718096  0.748824 -0.030728      down  cross down  388.8600
2022-07-08 12:30:00  0.569827  0.713024 -0.143197      down           0  387.9800
2022-07-08 12:45:00  0.412866  0.652993 -0.240127      down           0  387.5500
2022-07-08 13:00:00  0.255670  0.573528 -0.317858      down           0  387.1800
2022-07-08 13:15:00  0.176791  0.494181 -0.317390      down           0  387.7716
2022-07-08 13:30:00  0.155127  0.426370 -0.271243      down           0  388.3000
2022-07-08 13:45:00  0.145170  0.370130 -0.224960      down           0  388.4101
2022-07-08 14:00:00  0.141290  0.324362 -0.183072      down           0  388.4800
2022-07-08 14:15:00  0.174931  0.294476 -0.119545      down           0  388.9600
2022-07-08 14:30:00  0.247955  0.285171 -0.037217      down           0  389.5700
2022-07-08 14:45:00  0.350205  0.298178  0.052027        up    cross up  390.1700
2022-07-08 15:00:00  0.415148  0.321572  0.093576        up           0  390.0299
2022-07-08 15:15:00  0.462105  0.349679  0.112426        up           0  390.0400
2022-07-08 15:30:00  0.455337  0.370810  0.084527        up           0  389.5600
2022-07-08 15:45:00  0.436071  0.383862  0.052208        up           0  389.4500
2022-07-08 16:00:00  0.354582  0.378006 -0.023424      down  cross down  388.6800
```

Comment: Please show your column names, as well as the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if this works for you

```
def pct_diff(x, y):
    return (y - x) / x

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Direction'] == 'up':
        # Calculate percentage change to next cross-down price
        cross_down = df[i:][df['Direction'] == 'cross down'].iloc[0]['Price']
        df.loc[i, 'Pct Change'] = pct_diff(cross_down, row['Price'])
    elif row['Direction'] == 'cross down':
        # Reset cross-down price for next group of "up" rows
        cross_down = row['Price']
```

Comment: Ah ok, so basically you have to iterate and find the next value, there's no built in pandas mechanism for this? Thanks.